# Finding out the two nearest numbers to any float out of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, floating-point

I have a dict with floats as keys and objects as values.
I receive a float, and I'd like to know between what two keys this float is.
How do I find this?

Example of what I mean in code:

```
a = {}
a[1.2] = some_unimportant_instance
a[2.3] = some_other_unimportant_instance
a[2.6] = some_third_unimportant_instance
etc...

r = 2.5
# a[r] will not work
# I want something that returns the two numbers around r
# in this case, 2.3 and 2.6.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First observation: dict-s are bad for this. They are implemented using hashes and are efficient for retrieving values only for exact matches. For your purpose, you would have to first transform the dict into a list of keys. Then you could use modules such as bisect.

Example:

```
import bisect
keys = sorted(a.keys())
index = bisect.bisect(keys, r)
if index >= 1:
    print keys[index - 1]
print keys[index]
```

**UPDATE**: Code improved as suggested by Mark Dickinson. Thanks!

Comment: I would go a step further and say that a better model is a sorted list of tuples since you have to walk (at least part of) the list every time.

Comment: Wouldn't `keys = sorted(a.keys())` be better?  Also, don't you want `index >= 1` rather than `index > 1`?  You could also get rid of the duplicate call to bisect.bisect in the last line.

Answer (score 4):

It's Pythonic to use [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers). There are a number of MutableMapping types that maintain the keys in sorted order and support the bisecting and indexing you want. Consider the [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module which has a [SortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) type for exactly this purpose.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
sd = SortedDict((key, value) for key, value in data)

# Get the would-be index of the desired key.
index = sd.bisect(2.5)

# Get the actual key at that index.
key = sd.iloc[index]

# Look ahead one to find the range.
ahead = sd.iloc[index + 1]
```

sortedcontainers is also pure-Python, compatible with 2.6 through 3.4, has 100% test coverage and hours of stress, and has a [benchmark comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) showing it to be really fast (fast-as-C-implementations fast).

Answer (score 0):

To actually return the two keys, consider this:

```
def surrounding_keys(needle, haystack):
    if haystack: # ensure it's not empty
        keys = sorted(haystack.keys())
        for (lower, upper) in zip(keys, keys [1:]):
            if lower < needle < upper:
                return (lower, upper)
    raise KeyError # fails with key error if: not found, empty dict, dict with only one key
```